# C++ pointer wrong value

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

Relatively new to C++, I'm trying to learn using dynamic memory. In this case I'm using it to store member variables.

`Quanternion.h` -

```
#ifndef QUATERNION_H_
#define QUATERNION_H_

class Quaternion
{
private:

double* x = new double();
double* y = new double();
double* z = new double();
double* w = new double();

public:

Quaternion(double x, double y, double z, double w);

Quaternion(const Quaternion& q);

Quaternion& operator=(const Quaternion& q);

~Quaternion();

void setQ(double *_x, double *_y, double *_z, double *_w);

double * getX() { return x; }
double * getY() { return y; }
double * getz() { return z; }
double * getw() { return w; }
};
#endif
```

`Quanternion.cpp` -

```
#include "Quaternion.h"

Quaternion::Quaternion(double x, double y, double z, double w)
{
    double*a = &x;
    double*b = &y;
    double*c = &z;
    double*d = &w;

    setQ(a,b,c,d);
}

Quaternion::Quaternion(const Quaternion & q)
{
    this->x = q.x;
    this->y = q.y;
    this->z = q.z;
    this->w = q.w;
}

Quaternion & Quaternion::operator=(const Quaternion & q)
{
    if (this == &q)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    this->x = q.x;
    this->y = q.y;
    this->z = q.z;
    this->w = q.w;

    return *this;
}

Quaternion::~Quaternion()
{
}

void Quaternion::setQ(double *_x, double *_y, double *_z, double *_w)
{
    this->x = _x;
    this->y = _y;
    this->z = _z;
    this->w = _w;
}
```

When I create a Quaternion object and set the fields, and try and print one of the variables such as X by deallocating a pointer. I do not get the result I am expecting.

```
int main()
{

Quaternion q1(4, 9, 2, 5);

double*d = q1.getX();

cout << d << endl;
cout << *d << endl;
}
```

Example output -

```
00B1FB5C
6.26381e+148
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In this case your biggest mistake is to use dynamic memory ;). Try to find a better example. Using pointers and dynamic allocation in this case is not a solution (you dont need it!), but the source of so many problems with this code...

Comment: Honestly, i don't see what the downvotes are for... I know it's bad code, but this looks like a good excercise code (be it not really practical ;)

Comment: "by deallocating a pointer". Are you sure you are using the right term? Perhaps you are looking for the word "dereferencing".

Answer (score 2):

Your code violates basic principles of managing raw pointers - you have no idea who owns them. The same pointer might be an allocated entity through new, or simply an address provided in the constructor. That makes owning those impossible - you can't write assignment operators or copy constructors (your current implmentation is wrong).

The more immediate problem is that you are remembering address of arguments in your 4-doubles constructor. This is the immediate cause for dangling pointer and undefined behavior.

If you want to learn how to use pointers, you need to read a book about it. If you simply need to use pointer-like semantics, use smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you're compiler gave you some warnings. In your constructor, you take the address of of the four initializer arguments `x`, `y`, `z` and `w`. 
This is allowed, but only for using the address inside the constructor function itself. Because when the constructor function is done, these variables are not valid anymore, and therefore, pointers to them point to an invalid memory address (you don't know what's there anymore).

You have two options:

- don't use pointers; in this class you don't need them. Copying a pointer takes just as much work as copying a double.
- manage your pointers yourself. Create four `new double`s in your constructor, and change their value. It might also  be nice to look up `refreneces`.

I understand that you are trying to learn about pointers, but for this applications, pointers are really not necessary. And only make things slower. (Although not much).

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't have implementation of setQ here
2. You are trying to pass by value and getting the address of the value in 
   Quaternion(double x, double y, double z, double w)

Answer (score 0):

When You are trying to pass by value in Quaternion (double x, double y, double z, double w), You get the address of the value. After exit Quaternion (double x, double y, double z, double w) addresses are engaged in these variables are cleared away, and you are using is not your memory.